# winusb_initialize returns false

Tags: visual-c++, winusb

I use ZTE USB Modem device. My device installed to Ports class (driver is usbser.sys).
I followed msdn example "How to Access a USB Device by Using WinUSB Functions".
Everything is fine until I call the function winusb_initialize.It returns false with getlasterror 87 i-e ERROR_INVALID PARAMETER.I found a solution on "http://www.microchip.com/forums/m653017-print.aspx" but it doesn't help.when i try to change the winusb.inf file in x86 folder,computer says access is denied even though I have logged in as administrator.
Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you care about USB? Normally the modem just presents a "virtual" serial port for the modem. You can just use the modem as a normal serial device...

Comment: Actually i have to make a generalized program for any usb device.I have to complete the assignment using winusb.

Comment: the code snippet is  BOOL GetWinUSBHandle(HANDLE hDeviceHandle, PWINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE phWinUSBHandle)
{
    if (hDeviceHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    BOOL bResult = WinUsb_Initialize(hDeviceHandle, phWinUSBHandle);
    if(!bResult)
    {
        //Error.
        printf("WinUsb_Initialize Error %d.", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    return bResult;
}

Comment: How do you get the handle?

Comment: *hDeviceHandle = CreateFile (
        lpDevicePath,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL);

    if (*hDeviceHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        //Error.
        printf("Error %d.", GetLastError());
        goto done;
    }

Comment: And is the path and the handle valid?

Comment: lpdevice path is "\\?\usb#vid_19d2&pid_fff1&mi_03#7&62fd769&0&0003#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}" and hdevicehandle is 0x0013ED8C

Comment: lpdevicepath and handle both are valid

Comment: You should put this comments as EDIT's in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I you say your handle is good all you need to do is:

```
   BOOL bResult;
   WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE usbHandle;
   bResult = WinUsb_Initialize(deviceHandle, &usbHandle);
```

If `bResult` is `true`, it means you initialized the WinUsb correctly.